# Поиск по списку IP .txt

Tags: php

Входные данные:

```
ip => 123.1.1.3
```

Есть список .txt:

```
123.123.33.3
127.0.0.1
...
```

Нужна функция, которая вернет `true`, если в списке есть IP их входных данных или вернет `false` если IP в списке нет.

Comment: Насколько велик список? Можно засунуть его в оперативную память? Конвертнуть IP-адреса в целые числа?

Comment: Если небольшой список, можно воспользоваться `file` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php чтобы прочитать файл и перевести его в массив,  а затем применить `array_search` http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php для поиска в массиве значения

Comment: Аналогично можно читать построчно и проверять.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первый способ.

Если небольшой список, можно воспользоваться функцией **[file](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.file.php)**, чтобы прочитать файл и поместить его в массив, а затем применить **[array_search](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php)** для поиска в массиве значения. `array_search` осуществляет поиск данного значения в массиве и возвращает соответствующий ключ в случае удачи.

файл `IPs.txt`

```
123.123.33.3
127.0.0.1
```

Поиск

```
$ipToSearch = '123.1.1.3';
$ipList = file('IPs.txt');

echo array_search($ipToSearch, $ipList) ? 'YO!' : 'NO :-(';
```

---

Второй способ: использовать цикл (и функцию как обертку, чтоб не выпирал код :-) )

```
function findIP($ipToSearch, $file) {   
    $fp = fopen($file, 'r');

    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $line = trim(fgets($fp));

        if ($ipToSearch == $line)
            return true;            
    }

    fclose($fp);

    return false;
}   

echo findIP('123.1.1.3', 'IPs.txt') ? 'YO!' : 'NO :-(';
```

`fopen` - Открывает файл или URL

`fclose` - соответственно закрывает

`fgets` - Читает строку из файла

p.s. Также не стоит забывать обработку ошибок на наличие файла, на неудачную попытку считать, во время чтения и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$ip = "123.1.1.3";
$file = file_get_contents("ip.txt");
$array = explode(" ", $file);
if (in_array($ip, $array)) return true; // есть в файле
else return false; // нету
```